# The meaning of the phrase 'asked to make a fourth'

Tags: phrase-meaning

Consider:

> Lawson, on the lookout for models, had discovered a girl who was
>   understudying at one of the theatres, and in order to induce her to
>   sit to him arranged a little luncheon-party one Sunday. She brought a
>   chaperon with her; and to her Philip, **asked to make a fourth**, was
>   instructed to confine his attentions. He found this easy, since she
>   turned out to be an agreeable chatterbox with an amusing tongue.
>
> *Of Human Bondage by W. Somerset Maugham*

What does the bold part mean? Is it the number of times that Philip was asked?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Philip was asked to be '**a fourth**' member of their luncheon-party.

We have the girl (member no. 1), her chaperon (2), and Lawson (3). That makes Philip '**a fourth**'.

---

Examples of usage:

> I have no company but what is proper
>   To sit with the most flagrant whig at supper.
>   There's not a man among them but must please,
>   Since they're as like each other as are peas.
>   Toland and Hare have jointly sent me word,
>   They'll come; and Kennett thinks to **make a third**,
>   Provided he's no other invitation,
>   From men of greater quality and station.
>   ([Jonathan Swift, 1714](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Works_of_the_Rev._Jonathan_Swift/Volume_7/Horace,_Book_I._Ep._V.))
>   ...
>
> Poverty and zeal are an upper and a nether millstone. It is dangerous to **make a third** in that kind of sandwich. ([Ambrose Bierce](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Night-Doings_at_%22Deadman%27s%22))
>   ...
>
> To her cousins she became occasionally an acceptable companion. Though unworthy, from inferiority of age and strength, to be their constant associate, their pleasures and schemes were sometimes of a nature to **make a third** very useful, especially when **that third** was of an obliging, yielding temper; and they could not but own, when their aunt inquired into her faults, or their brother Edmund urged her claims to their kindness, that "Fanny was good-natured enough." ([Jane Austen](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Mansfield_Park/Chapter_II))

---

P.S. The correct form of my answering sentence is probably

> Philip was asked to become **the fourth** member of their luncheon-party.

I retained **a** to make it more understandable, more corresponing to the original quote.

---

P.P.S. As an aside, this construction was easy for me to understand, because in Russia we have a much-hackneyed stock question "третьим будешь?" which translates literally as "will you **be a third**?". It's not that different from "will you **make a third**?". The question is stereotypically used by (and ascribed to) tipplers who deem it ungentlemanlike to consume beverages in pairs, and so endeavor to gain a quorum of three. The phrase is used in movie episodes, especially of comic nature, and there are a number of jokes, like "Will you be a third? - Yes, sure! -Then let's go and find a second!"

[image]

Comment: As a side now, one can hear the expression "make a fourth" often on the linx, because golfers traditionally play in groups of four.

Comment: There are also card games, such as bridge, that require 4 people to play; in the US in the 40s and 50s, bridge was very popular among middle and upper classes, and "making a fourth" was also said for someone invited to play bridge with 3 others.